# Left and right continuity in metric spaces only for $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d_{M})$ and $(N,d_{N})$ be metric spaces and let $f:M\longrightarrow N$ be a function;

**Metric space definition of continuity:** $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in M$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $y\in M$

\begin{align*}
d_{M}(x,y)<\delta(\epsilon)\Longrightarrow d_{N}(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon
\end{align*}

If $M=N=(\mathbb{R}^{1},d_{1})$ this is just the definition of a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$, and in particular it can be modified to accommodate left and right continuous functions. For instance for right continuity;

**Definition of right continuity:** $f$ is right continuous at a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
-\delta(\epsilon)<x-y<0\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon
\end{align*}

If we now have $N=(\mathbb{R}^{1},d_{1})$ but $M=(\mathbb{R}^{2},d_{2})$ there are no longer only two ways in which a sequence $\{y_{n}\}\subset M$ can approach a point $x\in M$, indeed there are infinite ways this can occur.

**My questions are as follows**: I cannot recall separate definitions of continuity in particular directions when $N=(\mathbb{R}^{1},d_{1})$ but $M=(\mathbb{R}^{p},d_{p})$ for $p\geq 2$, and presumably this is simply because there are "too many of them" for this to be worth the effort, even though presumably this is possible? For more general metric spaces such as $M$ the Skorokhod metric of right-continuous functions on $D[0,1]$ and $N=(\mathbb{R}^{1},d_{1})$ it no longer even makes sense to talk about the direction that a sequence of functions in $D[0,1]$ can approach another function in $D[0,1]$?

I am probably missing something important, or it really is this obvious, but any help greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I realised now I knew of one example of a generalisation of "directional continuity" in probability theory from Billinglsey (3rd edition, 1995, P260)

If $\textbf{X}:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is a $p$-dimensional random vector with distribution $\mu:\mathscr{R}^{p}\longrightarrow [0,1]$ such that $P[\textbf{X}\in A]=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in\mathscr{R}^{p}$ and if $F:\mathbb{R}^{p}\longrightarrow [0,1]$ is the distribution function of $\textbf{X}$ then since $F$ is non-decreasing in each variable;

$$\text{lim}_{t\downarrow 0}F(x_{1}+t,....,x_{p}+t)=\text{lim}_{t\downarrow 0}F(\textbf{x}+t \textbf{1}_{p})=F(x_{1},...,x_{p})$$

where $\textbf{1}_{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{p}\backslash\{\textbf{0}\}$ denotes a vector of $1's$.

If we write $S_{\textbf{x}}=[\textbf{y}:y_{i}\leq x_{i},i=1,...,p]$ as the set with points "southwest" of $\textbf{x}$ then for a sequence $\{t_{n}\}$ such that $t_{n}\downarrow 0$ we have $S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n+1}}\subset S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}$ for all $n$ and $\cap_{n}S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n+1}}=S_{\textbf{x}}$, where $S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}$ is understood to mean $S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}\textbf{1}_{p}}$ which is the set containing the points southwest of $\textbf{x}+t_{n}\textbf{1}_{p}$. Billinglsey writes $S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}\downarrow S_{\textbf{x}}$ to denote this behaviour, suggesting a meaning of convergence "from above" of the sequence of southwest sets $\{S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}\}$ to the southwest set $S_{\textbf{x}}$.

Now for all $n$ we have

\begin{align}
F(x_{1}+t_{n+1},....,x_{p}+t_{n+1})&=\mu(S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n+1}})\\
&\leq \mu(S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}})\\
&=F(x_{1}+t_{n},....,x_{p}+t_{n}),
\end{align}

and $\text{lim}_{t\downarrow 0}F(x_{1}+t,....,x_{p}+t)=F(x_{1},...,x_{p})$ implies $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}F(x_{1}+t_{n},....,x_{p}+t_{n})=F(x_{1},....,x_{p})$. Billinglsey denotes both of these results as $F(x_{1}+t_{n},....,x_{p}+t_{n})\downarrow F(x_{1},....,x_{n})$, suggesting a convergence from above of $F(x_{1}+t_{n},....,x_{p}+t_{n})$ to $F(x_{1},....,x_{p})$.

In combination the convergence of the sequence $\{S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}\}$ of southwest sets from above to $S_{\textbf{x}}$ and the convergence of the sequence $\{F(x_{1}+t_{n},....,x_{p}+t_{n})\}$ of distribution function values to $F(x_{1},....,x_{p})$ satisfies the definition of $\mu$ being continuous from above if the southwest sets $\{S_{\textbf{x}+t_{n}}\}$ and $S_{\textbf{x}}$ are $\mathscr{R}^{p}$-measurable and $\mu(S_{\textbf{x}+t_{1}})<\infty$.

In general from Theorem 10.2 Billinglsey, p162, if $\mu$ is a measure on a field $\mathscr{F}$ then $\mu$ is continuous from above if for all $A_{n},A\in\mathscr{F}$ satisfying $A_{n}\downarrow A$ and $\mu(A_{1})<\infty$ implies $\mu(A_{n})\downarrow \mu(A)$.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you mean by “direction.” There’s a whole hierarchy of structure on metric spaces for each of which “direction” means different things… or simply doesn’t apply at all.

Comment: A function is right-continuous iff you have $\lim_{y \to x^+} f(y) = f(x)$, and this (to a point) absorbs similar notions in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in the sense that you can consider, say, $\lim_{t \to 0} f(x + tv)$ or $\lim_{t \to 0^+} f(x + tv)$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, cf. the definition of directional derivative for instance. For continuity in particular, the notion is perhaps simply not interesting enough to warrant its own name.

Comment: @BenSteffan thanks for your answer. I see now that the directional limit you give does indeed cover all of the infinite directions, thus enabling the concept of a directional continuity definition in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ for $p\geq 2$. The "lack of interest" thus must be the reason for the absence of this in mathematics. After reading your comment I have now added in an example from probability theory that accords with your answer: directional continuity is certainly possible, and sometimes is interesting enough to warrant it's own name

Comment: @WhileIAm thank you, yes indeed I was being vague (lazy), and Ben rescued me.